# Chef recipe to start weblogic server and nodemanager

Tags: bash, resources, weblogic, chef-infra, recipe

I have installed and configured weblogic with chef but struggling to start weblogic server and nodemanager with chef "Service" resource.

I tried with bash resource to directly run the startweblogicerver.sh file, however the process is not exiting and when I tried putting & at end then chef run successfully but weblogic didn't started.

Comment: There's a weblogic cookbook: https://supermarket.getchef.com/cookbooks/weblogic

Comment: Also see this question about backgrounding the server: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24592913/weblogic-server-to-create-domain-but-dont-start-it-chef-cookbook/24616495#24616495